# Contact Us JavaScript help

Tags: javascript

im trying to create a contact us web page, the obvious choice of posting the data would be to use the mailto function this obviously has some security flaws. i was wondering if there are any good javascript i can use to send the details from the contact us page to my email. i tutorial would be helpfull as i am really new to this.

Comment: Are you using any server side technology like php? If not your host provider may have a built in script to help. Where are you hosting the site?

Comment: Ivo Wetzel is right, you cannot send E-Mails via JavaScript, that'd be crazy. You must use some server side language, most likely PHP. PHP has a very simple to use E-Mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, there's no mail server built into any Browser. So besides the use of the `mailto:` link to fire up the E-Mail client, it would be really scary if you could send random E-Mails from a users computer via JavaScript, therefore basically turning every Browser into a spambox.

Do a nice JavaScript front end (if you really need WYSIWYG), with a fall back to a plain old HTML from, and handle the E-Mail stuff on the server side. Depending on your server, and language of choice that ranges from extremely trivial to the work of a day.